# PHP. Оптимальный разбор строки на ключ и значение из базы

Tags: php, eval

Добрый день. В базе есть поле params в которое помещаются произвольные ключи и значения в формате: key=>value, key2=>value2, ... и т.д.

После получения поля params в переменную $params, я забираю параметры следующим образом:

```
eval('$array=array(' . $params . ');');
extract($array);
```

Другими словами: есть строковая переменная:

```
$params = "key=>value, key2=>value2, key3=>value3"; //это не массив, это просто строка
```

Нужен алгоритм получения из этой строки обычного ассоциативного массива.

Чем eval крут, тем, что он корректно преобразует в массив даже такую строку:

```
$params = 'key=>"Lorem, ipsum; 22", key2=>[value2, value3, value4], key3=>value3';
```

Этот «алгоритм» работает, но меня смущает eval? Правильно ли мое решение? Есть ли более изящный и правильный способ?

Comment: А почему напрямую extract() не используется без eval()? Что-то мешает?

Comment: @cheops стрелка помешает...)

Comment: потому что там код исполняя создает массив

Comment: Извиняюсь, почему-то подумал, что params, это результирующий массив, а не строка.

Comment: @E.Dio пробегитесь циклом,  разбивая строку `k=>v` через explode   по символу `=>`..... и соберите массив.... а дальше этот массив уже делайте `extract`...... потому что `eval` это опасно и использовать его надо когда другоо выбора вообще больше нет

Comment: extract это зло вообще, используйте конкретную переменную массив со значениями напрямую без экстракта, не засоряйте программу неизвестными переменными.

Comment: вместо экстракта можно типа такого делать `if ($arrayOfVars !== null) {
 foreach ($arrayOfVars as $k => $v) {
  $$k = $v;
  unset($k, $v);
 }
}`   раньше у фремворка `kohana` так переменные в шаблон генерились....... eval точно лучше не юзать

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский eval в этом контексте чем может повредить? Прямого доступа к полю params нет.

Comment: @E.Dio сегодня нет прямого доступа - завтра есть. да и непрямой доступ всегда возможен.

Comment: ОК, ну тогда кроме проблем описанных в ответье г-ном Ипатьевым особо не вижу. Ибо реализовать одно что-то можно разными способами...Правда не думаю что кто-то стал бы параметры строкой в БД держаь....Как правильно подметил Ипатьев, если хотите параметры в строке держать, то хотя бы сделайте это как Json....но лучше в отдельной таблице конечно....... почему? да просто потому, что когда захочется изменить параметры, то что делать? не писать же алгоритмы по вычленению нужной информации, а потом её склеиванию.....в вашем же случае лично я б сделал как `kohana` предварительно распарсив строку

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за оказанное внимание. JSON - это решение моего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть.

Никаких "строк с параметрами" в базе данных даже близко быть не должно.
Значения в БД хранятся **каждое в своей ячейке.**

То есть вместо строки должна быть ТАБЛИЦА. с теми самыми парами ключ значение.

Получать так

```
$array = $pdo->query("SELECT key, value FROM parameters")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

По поводу же "крутости" eval в преобразовании многомерных массивов, рекомендую открыть для себя JSON.

Comment: Спасибо, JSON это то, что надо!